# Access Specifier for Interface Declaration

Tags: java, interface, private, protected

Why protected/private access specifier cannot be used Interfaces declaration ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *can* declare a protected class or indeed a private one - but only within another one. At that point it's either visible to classes derived from the outer one (in the case of protected) or not (in the case of private):

```
public class Outer
{
    private static class NotVisibleToSubclassesOfOuter {}

    protected static class VisibleToSubclassesOfOuter {}
}
```

Comment: The same is also actual for interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

What does a private class mean? That it cannot be used ever outside this class? Why would you ever have such a class? (How would you run/test it?)

What would a protected class mean? That it can only be seen by classes that extend it. So when you type a class skeleton (some where outside the world) it is not visble but when we say extends the class dynamically becomes visible?

Package protected class makes sense - It is visible to the classes inside the package and not really for public consumption.

Comment: there is a reason behind private class. You want to have utility class that is used inside your library, but you don't want make it public. But since javac creates .java file per class it is a bit useless.

Comment: @Andrey then have that class as a private class to the Class that is using it :) Not a seperate a private class :) The OP was asking why classes dont have the private modifier. They don't have in Java because it makes sense to not have them :)

Comment: yes, and i agree. but i wanted to mention that private modifier of class is useless just in java, not it oop itself. in C# there is a private modifier for class and it is very meaningful there.

Answer (score 0):

There is no sense in having private or protected access specifiers for class or interface because these two makes more sense when it comes to variables or methods for achieving encapsulation of the data.

Comment: Both make sense when the type in question is a nested type, however. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as an access specifier in Java. The term is 'access modifier'.

(So all those interview questions you see asking what is the difference are nonsense.)